# Implementing feature store for ML pipline

Tags: featuretools

There is lot of discussion about feature store in ML pipeline.Typical use case is res usability of feature among different scientist working on different model.
Is featuretool supports feature store concept?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Featuretools can be used to build a feature store.

In fact, the library lends itself well to creating a feature store because it provides a structured API for defining and extracting features from raw data that leads to reproducible data pipelines. So, while this isn't something that is currently officially supported Featuretools in the Featuretools API, it is something people are doing with Featuretools.

If you'd be interested in seeing a feature store officially released by Featuretools, you're welcome to submit a request for it on [Feature Request Board](http://feedback.featurelabs.com). That way other users can vote on it and developers can prioritize implementing it.